# Regex Capturing Group in Hugo

Tags: regex, hugo, hugo-shortcode

Recently I wanted to switch my [static site generator](https://jamstack.org/generators/) from [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to Hugo. I really like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/), but unfortunately, the usage of some functions often bothered me.

---

consider the code below,

```
{{ $my_var := `id="demo"` }}
{{ $my_slice := (findRE `id=\"(.*)\"` $my_var 1) }}
{{ index $my_slice 0 }}
```

reulst:

```
id="demo"
```

expected result

```
demo
```

In the above example, I want to get the value of the group.

Please note that what is really needed is a regular representation to get the group, not a tricky use of other functions (such as [replace](https://gohugo.io/functions/replace/) to replace the `id="` with a blank or something like that)

regex test website: https://regex101.com/

[image]

Please help me, I really spent a lot of time searching but still nothing. I found someone with the same question in [Hugo-discourse](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/accessing-findre-named-capture-groups/21427), but it's been a year and still no answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with `replaceRE`, where `$1` is your group number.

```
{{ $my_var := `id="demo"` }}
{{ $result := replaceRE `id=\"(.*)\"` "$1" $my_var }}
{{ $result }} → "demo"
```

Comment: Thank @modInfo, I decided to choose you as the best answer, although your answer does not extend, but without your inspiration, I would not have found out more, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @modInfo for the inspiration, I decided to expand the answer of [replaceRE](https://gohugo.io/functions/replacere/)

## by order

```
{{ $my_var := `id="demo"` }}
{{ $result := replaceRE `id=\"(.*)\"` "$1" $my_var }}
{{ $result }} → "demo"
```

## name group

```
{{ $my_var := `id="demo2"` }}
{{ $result := replaceRE `id=\"(?P<my_id>.*)\"` "$my_id" $my_var }}
{{ $result }} → "demo2"
```

more example

```html
{{ $my_var := `<h2 id="#demo+1-3%./2\"><a href="https://www.google.com/"></a></h2>` }}
{{ $id := replaceRE `.*id=\"(?P<my_id>([:#a-z0-9+\-%./\\])*)\">(<a href=\"(?P<my_href>[:#a-z0-9+\-%./\\]*)\">.*)?` "$my_id" $my_var }}
{{ $id }}  → #demo+1-3%./2\
{{ $href := replaceRE `.*id=\"(?P<my_id>([:#a-z0-9+\-%./\\])*)\">(<a href=\"(?P<my_href>[:#a-z0-9+\-%./\\]*)\">.*)?` "$my_href" $my_var }}
{{ $href }}  → https://www.google.com/
```